# Excess dishwasher water

Tags: kitchens

I have noticed there is approx. 12mm of water left inside my dishwasher after the cycle is complete. Have check the filters and they are all clean and clear. Any suggestions as to what the problem is?

Comment: Is this standing water new behavior? Most dishwashers leave water in the sump and pump after draining. Where is the 12mm depth measured?

Comment: I believe it is a new thing - the water is laying around in the bottom of the dishwasher interior whereas before it was only in the sump where the filter lives

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will have a go at pulling apart and cleaning properly

Comment: Thanks for the help. Have cleaned out clogged soap & it's draining all the water now.

Answer (score 1):

Many dishwashers use a float switch to kill the pump when the water level drops, these can get crusty with mineral/soap deposits and start acting up. Check/clean the float switch.

They also can lose pumping efficiency when the pump, pump volute, or/and discharge passages including hoses and air-gap are affected by sediment/scale/soap deposits. When the float switch tells the controller that the water level has dropped, the pump runs for a few seconds to remove the last of the water. The "few seconds" of run time does not remove as much remaining water with an occluded pump/volute/pump-out passage.

Remove, take apart, and clean the entire pump and macerator (yes, most have a macerator which is like a mini garbage grinder to break up materials that get by the screen) assemblies. And check your discharge hoses, air-gap, and drain for obstructions.

Comment: I personally think a gunked up pump/discharge path is the likely culprit. I have taken many apart that were just completely full of hard soap deposits. I had the same problem with *my own* dishwasher. I think the cheap detergents cause it, I started using only translucent dishwasher soap that comes in pre-measured "gel packs" and I have not had a problem since.